# CapabilityApi does not return any Nodes

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I'm attempting to communicate between my handheld and wearable app and I am trying to find the correct `Node` by using the `CapabilityApi`. I know that the devices are connected - other apps and samples work just fine - but when I run my wearable app neither calls to `getCapability()` or `getAllCapabilities()` return any `Nodes` at all.

Everything else seems to work properly - in fact I can find the handheld device just fine if I use the `NodeApi` and sending messages with the `MessageApi` also seems to work properly - but the capabilities of each device are just not advertised for some reason. I have properly setup the wear.xml in the res/values folder and I made sure that both apps have the same applicationId set in the build.gradle.

The calls to the `CapabilityApi` in my wearable app look like this:

```
Wearable.CapabilityApi.getCapability(mGoogleApiClient, SOME_CAPABILITY, CapabilityApi.FILTER_REACHABLE)
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<CapabilityApi.GetCapabilityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(CapabilityApi.GetCapabilityResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    return;
                }

                final CapabilityInfo info = result.getCapability();
                updateCapabilities(info);
            }
        });
```

But the `Set<Node>` in the `CapabilityInfo` instance is always empty! Also using `Wearable.CapabilityApi.getAllCapabilities()` always returns an empty `List<Node>`!

And for the record the wear.xml of my handheld app looks like this:

```xml
<resources>
    <string-array name="android_wear_capabilities">
        <item>some_capability</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I have combed through my codebase looking for an error but I just can't find it. It doesn't make any sense why the capabilities are not advertised.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Short answer:

Use the same debug certificate for both the handheld and wearable app, otherwise the `CapabilityApi` won't work.

---

### Long Answer:

The error turned out to be pretty simple! Fixing it just involves editing the signingConfig in the build.gradle.

I was using a common debug certificate for signing the debug builds of my handheld app:

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file("debug.jks")
        storePassword ...
        keyAlias ...
        keyPassword ...
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        ...
    }
}
```

But my wearable app was not using that same debug certificate, it was apparently using the default debug certificate supplied by my IDE. It seems that when the handheld and wearable app are not using the same certificate - even when it is just a debug build - then the capabilities of a device cannot be found by the other one. Which makes a lot of sense actually, what makes this whole thing confusing is that everything else seems to work just fine and as such pinpointing a problem like this is difficult.

In my case I removed the common debug singing config from the build.gradle of my handheld app and the `CapabilityApi` started working immediately. I think setting the same debug signingConfig for the wearable and handheld app would also fix the problem but I didn't test that for now.

Comment: I can confirm that setting the same `keystore` for both modules also work fine

Comment: Same logic but don't forget that if you use in your mobile manifest :    
**applicationIdSuffix ".debug"** you should also duplicate in your wearable manifest however you will result in different package name with same problem.

Comment: I am using the default debug signing for both modules (app and wearable), yet getting the same empty nodes set.

Answer (score 2):

Check if:

- ApplicationId in build.gradle for both modules is the same
- The package name for both modules is the same

Answer (score 0):

If you have both the build types (release & debug) on any side add the other one as well. Like i have both the build types on mobile side:

```
//Mobile side
    buildTypes {
            release {
     signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
     debug {
                applicationIdSuffix = ".debug" // just add debug build type to your watch build.gradle file as well
    }
    }
```

So i have added

```
//wear side
     debug {
                    applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
        }
```

But don't forget the applicationidsuffix should be same on both side