# Android Wear device not detecting any Nodes (phones) DataApi

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I have and android wear and android phone app. I'm trying to get them connect and ultimately send messages from the watch to the phone. On the watch though,  Wearable.CapabilityApi.getCapability() returns no nodes

Here is the Wear MainActivity:

```html
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "WatchApp";
    public GoogleApiClient mApiClient;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_MS = 1000;
    public static String nodeId;
    private static final String AIR_LIFT_CAPABILITY = "airlift";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initApi();

        final Button btnUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUp);
        btnUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = "Preset";
                //mAdapter.add( text );
                //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                sendMessage( text );
                Log.i("WatchApp", "btnUp  Sent Preset");

            }
        });

        Button btnDown = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDown);
        btnDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               String text = "AirOut";
                //mAdapter.add( text );
                //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                sendMessage(text );
                Log.i("WatchApp", "btnUp  Sent AirOut");
            }
        });

        // Enables Always-on
        setAmbientEnabled();



    }


    private void initApi() {
        mApiClient = getGoogleApiClient(this);
        setOrUpdateNotification();
        Log.i("WatchApp", "initApi()");

    }

    private GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient(Context context) {
        return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .build();

    }



    private void setOrUpdateNotification() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CapabilityApi.GetCapabilityResult result =
                        Wearable.CapabilityApi.getCapability(
                                mApiClient, AIR_LIFT_CAPABILITY,
                                CapabilityApi.FILTER_REACHABLE).await(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                updateFindMeCapability(result.getCapability());

                CapabilityApi.CapabilityListener capabilityListener =
                        new CapabilityApi.CapabilityListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCapabilityChanged(CapabilityInfo capabilityInfo) {
                                updateFindMeCapability(capabilityInfo);
                            }
                        };

               // Wearable.CapabilityApi.addCapabilityListener(mApiClient, capabilityListener, AIR_LIFT_CAPABILITY);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void updateFindMeCapability(CapabilityInfo capabilityInfo) {
        if (capabilityInfo.getNodes() == null) return;
        Set<Node> connectedNodes = capabilityInfo.getNodes();
        if (connectedNodes.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG,"No Nodes Found.");
        } else {
            for (Node node : connectedNodes) {
                // we are only considering those nodes that are directly connected
                if (node.isNearby()) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"FOUND NODE");
                    nodeId = node.getId();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void sendMessage(final String MESSAGE) {
        if (nodeId != null) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mApiClient.blockingConnect(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mApiClient, nodeId, MESSAGE, null);
                    mApiClient.disconnect();
                    Log.i("WatchApp", "Message ("+MESSAGE+") sent");
                }
            }).start();
        } else {
            Log.i("WatchApp", "No Nodes to send message!");
        }
    }





    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mApiClient.disconnect();
        mApiClient = null;
        Log.i("WatchApp", "onDestroy()");
    }


}
```

Wear AndroidManifest:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.schoen.jonathan.airliftwatch">


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="true" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.schoen.jonathan.airliftwatch.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Phone MainActivity:

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    boolean mBound = false;

    public static final String TAG = "PhoneApp";
    public ListenerService listener;
    public GoogleApiClient client;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        Button btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);


        Log.i("PhoneApp", "onCreate() Receiver Registered ");
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i("PhoneApp", "btnStart  Receiver Registered");
            }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i("PhoneApp", "btnStop  Receiver unRegistered");
            }
        });



        registerListener();
    }

public void registerListener() {
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
    listener = new ListenerService();
    Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(client ,listener);
    Log.i("PhoneApp", "registerListener() Listener Registered ");
}

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        registerListener();
        Log.i("PhoneApp", "onStart() Listener Registered ");
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        registerListener();

        Log.i("PhoneApp", "onResume() Listener Registered ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        //unregister our receiver
        if (client != null && listener != null)
            Wearable.MessageApi.removeListener(client, listener);
        client = null;
        listener = null;
        Log.i("PhoneApp", "onPause() Listener Unregistered ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        //unregister our receiver
        if (client != null && listener != null)
            Wearable.MessageApi.removeListener(client, listener);
        client = null;
        listener = null;
        Log.i("PhoneApp", "onPause() Listener Unregistered ");
    }
}
```

Phone Listener Service:

```html
public class ListenerService extends WearableListenerService {

    String nodeId;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        nodeId = messageEvent.getSourceNodeId();
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, messageEvent.getPath());
        showToast(messageEvent.getPath());


        String msg_for_me = messageEvent.getPath();

        if (msg_for_me == "AirOut")
        {
            Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Air Out");
        } else if (msg_for_me == "Preset")
        {
           
            Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Preset");
        }
       
    }

    

    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Phone Android Manifest:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.schoen.jonathan.airliftwatch">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <service
            android:name="com.schoen.jonathan.airliftwatch.ListenerService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Phone wear.xml:

```html
<resources>
    <string-array name="android_wear_capabilities">
        <item>airlift</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Any ideas why I get null result for returned nodes? my phone and watch are currently paired and i get updates on my watch from my phone from things like facebook and emails.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793711/is-nodeapi-specific-to-android-wear), NodeApi can be used on the device side.

```
NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = 
    Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mApiClient).await();
```

Then for each node within nodes, you can call `getDisplayName()`.

Also, based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755682/capabilityapi-does-not-return-any-nodes), use the same debug certificate for both the handheld and wearable app, otherwise the `CapabilityAPI` won't work.